# javascript - parse json string to object without quotes

Tags: javascript, json

Say below example:

```
    var mystring = `{
    name: "hello",
    value: 1234
    }`
    var jsonobj = JSON.parse(mystring)
```

It will output nothing since the "name" and "value" key without quotes. how can I parse such string to json object? I would not like to add quotes one by one!

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval(), but be careful with eval.

Comment: How can they use eval()? And why should they be careful with it? Those will likely be useful for someone unfamiliar with what eval() does.